# This table does not contain a unique column. Error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in my database, but when I want to change something with double click option phpMyAdmin keeps printing this error:

> "This table does not contain a unique column. Features related to the
>   grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete links may not work after
>   saving."

But there is unique `column(id)` and primary `column(id)` as you can see in my picture below.

[image: PHPMyAdmin]

It is really confusing, because I don't know what is the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version do you have?

Comment: my PHP is version: 5.5.27

Comment: Could you also tell me your phpMyAdmin version? Version information is available on the main page or sometimes in the browser title bar.

Comment: Version information: 4.5.2, latest stable version: 4.5.5.1

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this problem, so a few things you could try: Clearing your browser cache and reloading the page, copying the table to a new database and trying there, or exporting your structure (not data) and editing your question to add that so I can try with exactly your table structure as it exists in MYSQL.

Comment: when I copied the table it worked :) , but I still have not found out what is wrong with the old one.

Comment: Did you try clearing the browser cache? You might try from another browser entirely, or if that is not convenient try clearing your phpMyAdmin cookies (they start with "pma") and see if that helps.